# Intellij IDEA's key map gets messed up and almost empty every time I restart

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IDEA 2016.3.4 and since I've updated about 3 updates ago, my key maps and schemes get messed up every time I restart the IDE. I have a backup of my configuration, which I have to import every after restart (which triggers another restart) to fix the key maps. My custom schemes are kept in tact, but the one selected from the last session is almost empty. Not even ⌘ + Z works. I just don't know where the problem is coming from, especially when importing the key maps, and schemes every time don't seem to cause any problems.

Does anyone have an idea where I should look?

Comment: Did you do a clean shutdown of the IDE after changing the configuration? I have the same problem if i force quit the application instead of a clean shutdown (i.e. no `<alt>`+`<F4>` on windows or `<cmd>`+`<q>` on mac).

Comment: What do you mean by clean showdown?

Comment: I was editing the earlier response, check for update :-)

Comment: ⌘ + Q is the only way to shut it down on OS X. Even if I go to the menu, that's the shortcut I'm given.